# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'app.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'
```

I installed everything, even whitenoise and imported all, I still cant get rid of this error

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]? How did you install what exactly? How do you try to run your code?

Comment: pip install whitenoise , pip install django-cors-headers, first installed the corsheaders without any thirdparty installation, then I configured it in the settings as above after looking for the solution, I installed whitenoise but t didn't work as well.